# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC with Blazor - Missing Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to follow this tutorial about [using Blazor in my existing apps](https://jonhilton.net/use-blazor-in-existing-app/) with Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.3 (non-preview). I first created a new Core 3.1 MVC Web App to test it out, before implementing it to my other apps. But at the part where I need to write the `<component>` tag helper in the `Index.cshtml`, I keep getting this:

```
The type or namespace name 'HelloWorld' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here is my `Index.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<component type="typeof(HelloWorld)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

and here is my `HelloWorld.razor`:

```
@page "/Hello"

<h3>HelloWorld</h3>

@code {
}
```

I placed the `HelloWorld.razor` in a `Pages` folder at the root of my solution. Also, if needed, here are the `Startup.cs` methods that were changed:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    });
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the tutorial I linked in the original post is missing something. Instead of:

```
typeof(HelloWorld)
```

it should be something like this:

```
typeof(<namespace name>.<the folder the .razor file is in>.<the .razor file name>)
```

so in my case, it should look like this:

```
typeof(TestMVCBlazor.Pages.HelloWorld)
```